# Python 3.5 вопрос по работе eval()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно в цикле создать переменные, имена которых будут браться из списка. Для начала, я хочу проинициализировать их нулями.э

```
for k in DEV.lst:
    eval("steps_" + str(int(k.con)) + " = 0")
```

Интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\and\Desktop\Бойлерная\python\autogen_s7-1200_v1.py", line 605, in <module>
    eval("steps_" + str(int(k.con)) + " = 0")
  File "<string>", line 1
    steps_270 = 0
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Но мне как раз нужно создать переменную с именем steps_270.
Почему не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` используется для expressions. Для statements используй `exec`.

Про разницу между ними хорошо написано, например, [в этом вопросе на английском Стэковерфлоу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728073/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-python).

А вообще использовать динамическую генерацию кода плохо – неочевидно, просто ошибиться, трудно отлаживать, трудно читать. Поэтому лучше сделай `steps` списком.

Answer (score 3):

Идея динамически создавать переменные не очень хорошая, но если уж очень нужно, то лучше это сделать не с помощью eval, а так:

```
for k in DEV.lst:
    globals()['steps_' + str(int(k.con))] = 0
```