# Обьявление переменных в цикле python

Tags: python

```
def variables(date):
    for key in date:
        global key
        key = date['key']
```

Реально ли сделать механизм по которому, цикл пробегаться по словарю и объявляет переменную с именем ключа и которой присваивается соответствующее значения из этого же словаря.
P.S. нужно для написания модуля который предназначен для реализации мультиязычности в программе, т.е. доступ к соответствующему словарю языка который берется из файла json и выводу из него сообщения по ключу(mess_id).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python 3.5 вопрос по работе eval()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519033/python-3-5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-eval)

Answer (score 1):

Идея динамически создавать переменные не очень хорошая, но если уж очень нужно, то можно так:

```
def variables(date):
    for key, value in date.items():
        globals()[key] = value
```