# Значение итерации в переменной цикла for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите реализовать в python. Есть список по которому проходит цикл for. На выходе нужно получить переменные btn + номер итерации = соответствующему значению цикла.

```
distances (50, 100, 200, 400, 800)

    for index, items in enumerate(distances, 1):
        btn[index] = items
                print (btn[index])

Требуемый результат:

btn1 = 50
btn2 = 100
btn3 = 200
btn4 = 400
btn5 = 800
```

Comment: `print(f'btn{index} = items')`

Comment: Эта строка выведет на экран, а мне нужно чтобы переменным btn... присваивались значения.

Comment: в таком случае, [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742176/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-python) топик может быть полезен